# GAE python: How to post/retrieve json data between two applications?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have two gae apps and want to send data between the two.

First app(localhost):

```
import requests

class PostHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        post_url = "https://www.example.com/api/post"
        datas = lib.data_cache()
        output = [data.as_dict() for data in datas]
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        #self.write(output)
        r = requests.post(post_url, data=json.dumps(output), headers=headers)
```

www.example.com:

```
class RetrieveHandler(Handler):
     def post(self):
        post_data = self.requests.POST.items()
        #What should I do here? Is this correct?
```

I'm not getting the post_data properly. Anyone knows where I can get documentation on this in python and app engine?  Any advice would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting that error?

Comment: What is Handler? webapp2.RequestHandler?

Comment: Oh nvm actually, I made a mistake in the url... However, the POST items are not getting the data, how would I get the data?

Comment: Are you using webapp2?

Comment: Yes, I'm using webapp2. And I tried self.request.GET.items(), not working either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using webapp2, you can extract POST request body data with a webapp2.RequestHandler instance like this

```
data = self.request.body
```

Because you are sending JSON, you probably want to parse that right away

```
data = json.loads(self.request.body)
```

Also see https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#common-request-attributes for what other info you can get from the `request` object.

Comment: Perfect! got the data!

Comment: is it possible to use: data = json.load(self.request.body) ? Would there be increase in efficiency?

Comment: @mparkes no, that is the method to load json from a file object